# Why am I getting a html file instead of json?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, fetch-api

```
#import libraries

import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
#request the api endpoint

url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/owners?limit=20&order_by=created_date&order_direction=desc"
response = requests.get(url)

print(response.text)
```

I was trying get details of owners using an api endpoint from opensea but I am getting a html file insteadd of json file

Comment: Please post code rather than pictures. You're getting "Access denied", where the server probably tries to redirect you to a login page. You probably need to pass authorization headers/cookie with your requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all use format json in url like

your url

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/owners?limit=20&order_by=created_date&order_direction=desc

changed url (just add its format to json)

https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/owners?format=json&limit=20&order_by=created_date&order_direction=desc

2. then you can use json function like this

```py
url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/owners?format=json&limit=20&order_by=created_date&order_direction=desc"
response = requests.get(url)

print(response)
```

Comment: <bound method Response.json of <Response [403]>>
I'm getting like this

Comment: maybe your url is protected by cloudflare